# How can I keep my calendar always on top of shared calendars in Outlook's overlay view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, overlay

I am using Outlook 2010 at work. We have a calendar each that we share with other colleagues so that we are aware of each other's whereabouts. I like the overlay view because it gives me all the information I need in a relatively small space on the screen.

Everything works well appart from one detail: when I open the calendar view, the top calendar is **always** one of my colleague's (never mine for some reason).

So I move to my calendar tab, add something, go back to my emails and when I come back to the calendar view, the top calendar is **AGAIN** one of my colleagues'.

I really wish I could find a way to tell Outlook to stop playing with my nerves like that but I can't seem to find anything useful on the forums or MS help.

Does anyone know how to keep my calendar on top in overlay view?

What I get (my colleague's calendar on top):

[image: my colleague's calendar on top]

What I would like to get (without having to click on my calendar's tab before editing):

[image: my calendar on top]

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful

Comment: I just looked at my own, I think you have office 2010, the toolbar is updated from the 2007 one (which is what I have) *Yup just googled and its 2010, I looked through the settings for mine but I don't have multiple calendars and I can't find anywhere to change the default, sorry. Someone with 2010 will need to help ya out

Comment: Don't know if it'll work, but maybe try this: You need to change the default calendar by changing the default personal folder file (PST).

Click on file->Data file management->Click on the personal folder that has the calendar you need to show as default-> Set it as default.
(https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/how-to-set-default-calendar-for-populating/6c613320-4ecb-477f-be62-894a5786ad6b)

Comment: Also picture tutorial here, but its for 2013. Seems the same though to me. (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-default-calendar-7c546486-0c7c-4870-964a-0d6eb4de83e0)

Comment: Try to call Outlook with the command switch `/resetnavpane`. You will need to re-open the shared calendars

Comment: @JCTechie Good spot it is OutLook 2010! I already checked the PST and it points to my account. @harrymc I tried the `/resetnavpane` which worked for the current session but today I am back in the same situation as before. Shame I cannot send calendar invites everyday to my team mates!

Comment: I don't have Outlook 2010, but see how your calendar is situated in the My Calendar and Other Calendars groups in the Navigation Pane. The order from top to bottom is how the Calendars will be listed in the main body. Right-click and Move Up your calendar to the top of the list.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, I tried that already but to no avail, it just changes the order of the calendar tabs but doesn't seem to have any effect on which one gets the focus by default.

Comment: This may possibly be an Outlook bug. Is Outlook fully patched? Have you tried with later Outlook versions?

Comment: @harrymc This is my work PC, I have linux at home so no other versions of Outlook to try. My gut feeling is that Outlook sends asynchronous queries for the shared calendars and gives the focus to the last one that came in. It would explain the semi-randomness of which calendar gets the focus but I haven't got any elements to validate this theory.

Comment: This is still a bug. To work around it you will maybe need to write a VBA macro that captures the get-focus event and resets the current calendar. It might be simpler to keep on clicking the calendar's tab. For bug reports to Microsoft, I think the [Outlook help center](https://support.office.com/en-us/outlook) only handles recent Outlook versions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see is that you have the calendars on different calendar groups, and for some reason that is confusing the Outlook client.

The groups on the left named "My Calendars" and "Shared Calendars" are the default grouping for calendars, however, you can create your own and give them the order you want. You can either move all of the calendars into one of the existing groupings, or create a new group. The procedure is quite simple:

1. Right clic on top of one of the groupings and select New Calendar Group (give it a name)
2. Right clic on each calendar and move them up or down so that they enter your newly created group, and place them in the order you want to be displayed on your screen.

Comment: Interesting, it seems to work so far...

Comment: It worked for a while but it's now back to the same behaviour (note we are now using office 365). Thanks for your suggestion though.